# Bundling failed: on modules that I don't use

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, npm-install

After changing from my windows laptop visual studio code to my ubuntu visual studio code (just copy paste the files) I am getting some weird errors for bundling failed for modules that I dont even use in my app like the below one:

```
Android Bundling failed 5254ms
Unable to resolve module @rneui/base/dist/AirbnbRating/index from /home/apanay22/Desktop/GitHubBestThesis/TIBaLLi-project-voice-services/node_modules/@rneui/themed/dist/AirbnbRating/index.js: @rneui/base/dist/AirbnbRating/index could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  1 | import { withTheme } from '../config';
> 2 | import { AirbnbRating, } from '@rneui/base/dist/AirbnbRating/index';
    |                                ^
  3 | export { AirbnbRating };
  4 | export const AirbnbRatingDefault = withTheme(AirbnbRating, 'AirbnbRating');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't figure it out why it happened.. probably because of the versions and the dependencies.

I followed this procedure and the problem fixed:

1. npm install
2. npm cache verify
3. npm uninstall @rneui/base and then npm install @rneui/base

This solve the problem for me

Answer (score 3):

You only need this package

```
npm install @rneui/base @rneui/themed
```